# PHP / Jquery multidimensional array

Tags: php, jquery, chartist.js

I need to return a PHP array to Jquery, with the following format:

```
{
  labels: [1, 2, 3],
  series: [
    [
      {meta: 'description', value: 1},
    ],
  ]
}
```

How can I do this? I tried a few ways, and the one I came closest to is an index inserted in the path.

```
$return = array(
                 "labels" => [1,2,3],
                  "series" => [
                        array(
                            "meta" => ['description'],
                            "value" => [1],

                        ),
                    ],  

                );
```

Comment: Seems like all you need to do is remove the brackets around `description` and `1`.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. Needs another array level in `series`.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you just have to make two corrections:

- there's an array level missing under `series`
- `value` and `meta` values shouldn't be arrays

Your array should look like this before encoding:

```php
$return = array(
    "labels" => [1,2,3],
    "series" => [ // numeric array, will be encoded as array
        [ // also numeric array, will be encoded as array (this one was added)
            array( // associative array, will be encoded as object
                "meta" => 'description', // value not placed in an array
                "value" => 1, // value not placed in an array
            ),
        ],
    ],
);
```

Comment: I tried it that way. An index 0 is added to the array. `labels: ["MP", "CF", "CI", "CE", "TB", "TR", "DT", "ML"]
series: [[,…]]
0: [,…]
0: {meta:...`

Comment: What you're describing doesn't correspond with the structure I have proposed. The array in my answer produces exactly what you wrote in your question as the desired result (see [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/sk13s)). If you're not getting what you need, then your array isn't structured like this and you should debug it.

Comment: You are right. But I don't know why the use of this plugin is not working. [link](https://github.com/tmmdata/chartist-plugin-tooltip)

Comment: I can't help you with that, since I don't know what you're actually doing. You have written a question about a sample and we have established how the PHP array needs to be structured to match that sample. If you're having trouble with your code that builds this, then your question should have been about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
<?php
    
    $return = array(
                     "labels" => [1,2,3],
                      "series" => [
                            array(
                                (object)[
                                    "meta" => 'description',
                                    "value" => 1,
                                ]
                            ),
                        ],  
    
                    );
    
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($return);
    print_r(json_encode($return));
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Did not work. I think I will have to change the way of passing this array.